# Is there a jquery event associated with the mouse leaving a subModal window?

Tags: jquery

I'm using a subModal window (basically a floating frame) for a login prompt. Is there a way to trigger an event when the mouse leaves the floating frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's called [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)

> Bind an event handler to be fired **when the mouse leaves an element**, or trigger that handler on an element.

Comment: Thank you.. I was trying .focusout() -- Is the whole page considered the element here?

Comment: No, there is no lose of focus since there are no mouse clicks or key strokes.

Comment: .mouseout() ended up working best for me, .mouseleave() triggers on buttons when it shouldn't apparently. Thanks for the nudge in the right direction!